# C - How do I use realloc with pointers

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm having trouble using realloc in this case. My compiler, devC++, keeps telling me it's an invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct WaitlistEntry'. I'm basically trying to malloc a struct using the given structs, and then store the data in it.

Here is the entire function:

```
void attemptEnrollment( Course* pCourse, int iStudentID, int iPriority ){ 

    if (pCourse->iNumEnrolled < pCourse->iMaxEnrolled)
        enrollStudent(pCourse, iStudentID);
    else {
        WaitlistEntry w1;
        w1 = (struct WaitlistEntry*)malloc(sizeof(struct WaitlistEntry));
        w1.iStudentID = iStudentID;
        w1.iPriority = iPriority;
        waitlistStudent(pCourse,w1);
    }
}
```

Here are the structs:

```
typedef struct{
    int iPriority;          /* Priority of the student to be enrolled */
    int iStudentID;         /* ID of the student */
} WaitlistEntry;

typedef struct PQNode {
    WaitlistEntry info;     /* WaitlistEntry stored in the node (sorted with largest priority first) */
    struct PQNode* pNext;   /* Pointer to next node in the LL */
    struct PQNode* pPrev;   /* Pointer to previous node in the LL */
} PQNode;

typedef struct{
    int iCourseNumber;      /* Course number of the course */
    int* iStudentIDs;       /* Array of IDs of students enrolled in the course */
    int iNumEnrolled;       /* Number of Students currently enrolled in course */
    int iMaxEnrolled;       /* Max number of Students that can enroll in the course */
    PQNode* pFront;         /* Priority queue representing the waitlist for the course */
} Course;
```

Comment: You need to be consistent. The first line should be `typedef struct PWaitlistEntry` and you should use `struct PWaitListEntry` not `struct WaitlistEntry`

Comment: Why *return* void, if your intention is to allocate something useful? BTW for *linear reading* it is more convenient to place the struct definitions *before* their usage.

Comment: `WaitlistEntry w1;
        w1 = (struct WaitlistEntry*)malloc(sizeof(struct WaitlistEntry));` --> `WaitlistEntry *w1;
        w1 = malloc(sizeof(WaitlistEntry));`... `w1.iStudentID = iStudentID;` --> `w1->iStudentID = iStudentID;`

Comment: you didn't declare anything called `struct WaitlistEntry`.  You allocated an anonymous struct, with a typedef name of WaitlistEntry.  If you change the declaration to: ```typedef struct WaitlistEntry {
    int iPriority;          /* Priority of the student to be enrolled */
    int iStudentID;         /* ID of the student */
} WaitlistEntry;
``` you should have better luck

Comment: Or just change the `malloc()` argument to `sizeof(WaitlistEntry)`

Comment: Your trouble is not with `realloc` mostly. It is first to **declare your `struct`-s correctly and consistently.** BTW, your naming is poor. I would suggest `typedef struct WaitlistEntry_st {int iPriority; int iStudentID;} WaitlistEntry;` In C (but not C++) the names of `struct` tags and the names of `typedef` are in different "namespaces"

Comment: @DigWallace: Read some *existing* source code in some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) or [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/), etc...). That should inspire you a lot.

Comment: BTW, [DevC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) is *not* a compiler, but an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). On Windows, your compiler is likely MinGW that is some variant of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). On Linux it would probably be [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). On MacOSX, likely to be [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)

Comment: I should mention that these structs were given to me as part of the assignment, as well as the return type of the function. Everything people have mentioned about them, I've already questioned, so I'm glad to see it was warranted. That said, I believe they had this program working and mere snipped parts out and gave that as an assignment, so it should work somehow.

Comment: Whatever was given to you should be correctly compiled. If your instructor made some typos, you need to correct them.

Comment: I'll do what I must, but we were given instructions to not change certain parts.

Comment: BTW, your title mentions `realloc` that your shown code don't even use.... Next time, put more efforts in asking and formulating your question and read it several times before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused and need to read a book about C programming. Your trouble is first to declare your types and structures correctly and consistently. I would suggest:

```
typedef struct WaitlistEntry_st {
  int iPriority;          /* Priority of the student to be enrolled */
  int iStudentID;         /* ID of the student */
} WaitlistEntry;

typedef struct PQNode_st {
  WaitlistEntry info;     /* WaitlistEntry stored in the node
                             (sorted with largest priority first) */
  struct PQNode_st* pNext;   /* Pointer to next node in the LL */
  struct PQNode_st* pPrev;   /* Pointer to previous node in the LL */
} PQNode;

typedef struct Course_st {
  int iCourseNumber;      /* Course number of the course */
  int* iStudentIDs;       /* Array of IDs of students enrolled in the course */
  int iNumEnrolled;       /* Number of Students currently enrolled in course */
  int iMaxEnrolled;       /* Max number of Students that can enroll
                              in the course */
  PQNode* pFront;         /* Priority queue representing the waitlist 
                             for the course */
} Course;
```

Notice the consistency above: the tags of `struct`s (the name following immediately `struct`) is suffixed with `_st` (and in C - but not in C++ - names of `struct` tags are in a different namespace than names of `typedef`).

Then you would code

```
    WaitlistEntry* w1 = malloc(sizeof(WaitlistEntry));
    if (!w1) { perror("malloc WaitlistEntry"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    w1->iStudentID = iStudentID;
    w1->iPriority = iPriority;
```

notice that every call to `malloc` should be tested against failure.

BTW, I recommend **reading some *existing* code for inspiration**. You'll find a lot of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) code (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/) or [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/)) and reading some of it is inspirational and instructive.

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info. So pass `-Wall -Wextra -g` to your `gcc` compiler (perhaps a MINGW variant) used by your Dev-C++ IDE.

Comment: I should mention that these structs were given as part of my assignment. I think the implementation of them is intentional to a degree. I did have these suspicions, but we were given instructions of which parts to actually write, and for what I've posted, it's only what's inside the attemptEnrollment function. Not the return type, parameters passed, etc. That said, thanks for the input. I didn't think the structs would cause this big a problem actually.

Comment: Instructors are human, they do make typos and mistakes. But are you sure you copied code correctly in your question? It is so poorly asked and formulated that I would imagine you (not your instructor) made the typos.

Comment: Yes, I haven't touched that part at all. You can view the original [here.](http://www.codesend.com/view/9d28e6dc925795d0b09c0b23b563c09b/) - Edited with better formatted page.

Comment: I did, and it works up until the parts that require filling it.

Comment: Thenn I guess your instructor expects you to correct the typos.

Answer (score 1):

Either change:

```
typedef struct {
  // ...
} WaitlistEntry;
```

to

```
typedef struct WaitlistEntry {
  // ...
} WaitlistEntry;
```

I'd use this style if you choose to do that: (minus the comments)

```
// typedef's "struct WaitlistEntry" as "WaitlistEntry"
typedef struct WaitlistEntry WaitlistEntry;
// declares the contents of "struct WaitlistEntry"
struct WaitlistEntry {
  // ...
};
```

Which makes the meaning of the typedef more obvious. Mixing typedef and struct declarations can be a little confusing. (It also allows you to use `WaitlistEntry *` inside `WaitlistEntry`.)

Or you can change the `malloc` call to:

```
w1 = (WaitlistEntry *) malloc(sizeof(WaitlistEntry));
```

You should try be consistent with your usage: (If you use `WaitlistEntry` always use `WaitlistEntry`, if you use `struct WaitlistEntry` always use `struct WaitlistEntry`).